# Switch Constantly Tripping Breaker

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

can someone tell me why the switch circled in red is tripping the breaker? I was swapping them around. The other two seem to work fine. The far left is a fan timer (works), the middle is a simple switch (works), and the far right is a dimmer switch (not working).

[image: wiring]

[image: switch]

[image: boxlight]

Comment: Unless that's a switch loop (power goes to the ceiling fixture then comes down to the switch), you should _not_ have hot and neutral on the switch. It does look like there's a black line on that white wire, so maybe that's what it's indicating. Of course, who knows what's going on behind the box - the sheathing for that cable should run _into_ the box, not be cut off behind it.

Comment: Are you sure the polarity is correct (- to -, and + to +), and the loop is correct and complete? Can you add grounding?

Comment: Hi @r13, the ground it attached to the box, may be hard to see. But what do you recommend to do to prevent it from tripping? It happens immediately as soon as I flip it back down.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the inside of the box the light is attached to??

Comment: @JACK I have added it.

Comment: .....  the box the light is attached to, not the switch..  W want to clarify how those wire from the switch are hooked up to the light.

Comment: Disconnect the "output" side of the dimmer switch and see if flipping it to "on" still causes the break.  If it does, the switch is bad. If it doesn't, there's something bad in the run to the light box itself.

Comment: @zack I am not an electrician, but I guess there is a "fault" somewhere in the circus. Do you know the use of multimeter? It might help in finding the defect.

Comment: @JACK sorry, misread. I added the photo of the light box if that helps, thanks!

Comment: So I just swapped the dimmer switch with another dumb switch to see if it made any difference and it still tripped it. Even with the switch turned off (if that even matters).

Comment: You say "the middle is a simple switch" but it appears to be an electronic dimmer.  You say you swapped the offending dimmer (circled) with a "dumb" switch that tripped the cct even when off.  Can you show us that configuration in a photo?  TRY THIS:  Disconnect the two wires, circled red, entirely.  Plug each one with a separate wire nut.  Does the circuit still trip?   If yes, your problem is not with the dimmer.  If no, then there's something questionable about your saying that a dumb switch in the off position would cause a trip.  I hope this helps .... try this and give us more info.

Comment: @jay613 So I just tried that and still tripping... is there anything in the box that could be causing this? Or it's beyond the box now?

Comment: Let's assume for now that those two wires are not part of the problem.  Where is that yellow wire going, from the middle switch?  Is its bare end touching the metal side of the fan controller?   Put a wire nut on that and try again.

Comment: @jay613 Yes, I actually did nut it earlier right after this picture. It's just an optional wire for a 3-way switch. No difference sadly. Also, the middle switch is a Honeywell switch that just has an on/off function with a small dipsplay with time/date. I called it a "simple switch" because it is just an on/off button.

Comment: @r13 it's a metal box, and the switches all have metal yokes, and all the Romex grounds go to the box like they're supposed to. **The switches will pick up ground from the mounting screws once they're installled**. Yeah, you can do that.   For switches (and self-grounding receps).  The ground pigtails on the smart switches can simply be capped off for if they're ever reused in a plastic box... don't need 'em here.

Comment: The middle switch must be a timer.  Anyway.  You're going to have to dissect and triage this.  Label and disconnect everything.   Nut off all the loose wires.  Test.  One circuit at a time replace the switch with a known good simple on/off switch.  Test X3.  You are trying to isolate a short inside one of the switches or somewhere other than this box.  One of the three devices being controlled.   Before doing all this .. if you recently worked on any of those, go check your work.

Comment: Can you post photos of the *inside* of the box the light is attached to?

Comment: As part of the diagnostics here ... in your question you say that the left switch "works" but how do you know that if the circuit trips when the right switch is removed and its wires separately capped off?   What is the most recent configuration of all this that allows the breaker to remain on?

Answer (score 1):

I’m sorry for wasting everyone’s time. I made a complete mistake and I appreciate everyone’s suggestions. But after troubleshooting more I had an epiphany. The day before this started I did work on another switch that was on the same circuit and one wire came off and happened to touch the other. I reattached the one that came off and problem solved. Had nothing to do with anything in this box, but another.